# error al validar con jquery-validate en wizard bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

Estoy realizando una aplicación web con un wizard de bootstrap la primera pantalla tiene un formulario que valido con jquery-validate, en la segunda sección del wizard tengo un input y un botón que generan una tabla según el numero de filas que ingrese el usuario dentro del input, el problema viene después de generar la tabla ya que al pasar a la sección 3 de mi wizard, no me permite ya que me genera un error, identificando el error a través del google chrome es cuando verifico si es valido mi form con $("#commentForm").valid(), pero no se ¿Por que?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fecharecepcion').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es',
    format: "dd/MM/YYYY"
  });

  $('#fechaenvio').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es',
    format: "dd/MM/YYYY"
  });

  $.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "Este campo es obligatorio.",
    remote: "Por favor, rellena este campo.",
    email: "Por favor, escribe una dirección de correo válida",
    url: "Por favor, escribe una URL válida.",
    date: "Por favor, escribe una fecha válida.",
    dateISO: "Por favor, escribe una fecha (ISO) válida.",
    number: "Por favor, escribe un número entero válido.",
    digits: "Por favor, escribe sólo dígitos.",
    creditcard: "Por favor, escribe un número de tarjeta válido.",
    equalTo: "Por favor, escribe el mismo valor de nuevo.",
    accept: "Por favor, escribe un valor con una extensión aceptada.",
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, no escribas más de {0} caracteres."),
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, no escribas menos de {0} caracteres."),
    rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribe un valor entre {0} y {1} caracteres."),
    range: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribe un valor entre {0} y {1}."),
    max: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribe un valor menor o igual a {0}."),
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribe un valor mayor o igual a {0}.")
  });


  var $validator = $("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
      factura: {
        required: true
      },
      nombre: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
      },
      apellidoA: {
        required: true
      },
      apellidoM: {
        required: true
      },
      fecharecepcion: {
        required: true
      },
      fechaenvio: {
        required: true
      },
      emailfield: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        minlength: 3
      }
    }
  });

  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    'tabClass': 'nav nav-pills',
    'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
      var $valid = $("#commentForm").valid();
      if (!$valid) {
        $validator.focusInvalid();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });



  $("#btnGenerafilas").click(function() {


    //Iniciamos esta linea para que el Jquery no tenga conflicto con otras librerias que tengas
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery("#generaTabla").hide().fadeIn("Slow");
    //Capturamos el Numero de filas en la variable
    var NroFila = document.getElementById("txtNroFila").value;
    var Cantidad = NroFila * NroFila + 1;
    var valor = Cantidad * 1300;

    //removemos las filas que pueda tener la tabla
    jQuery('#tblTabla tr').next().remove();
    var a = 0;
    //Recorremos el NroFila y vamos creando las filas
    for (var x = 0; x < NroFila; x++) {
      Cantidad = Cantidad + x;
      valor = valor * Cantidad;
      a = a + 1;
      jQuery('#tblTabla tr:last').after('<tr>' +
        '<td align="left">' + a + '</td>' +
        '<td align="left">' + Cantidad + '</td>' +
        '<td align="left">' + valor + '</td></tr>');
    }
    //Colocamos algo de extra para colorear las filas :P
    jQuery('#tblTabla tr:odd').css('background-color', '#E9F0F8');
  });

});
```

```html
<form id="commentForm" method="get" action="#" class="form-horizontal">
  <div id="rootwizard">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" id="tabUno">1. Datos</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" id="tabDos">2. Articulos</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" id="tabTres">3. Series</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
        <!-- INICIA TAB1 -->
        <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Ingrese los datos solicitados</h5>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Factura</label>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="factura" name="factura" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Apellido Paterno</label>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidoA" name="apellidoA" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Apellido Materno</label>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidoM" name="apellidoM" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Fecha recepción</label>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fecharecepcion" id="fecharecepcion" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Fecha envio</label>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fechaenvio" id="fechaenvio" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- FIN TAB1 -->

      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <!-- INICIA TAB2 -->
        <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Ingrese</h5>
        <div id="ingresaFilas">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Ingrese</label>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNroFila" name="txtNroFila" />
              <button id="btnGenerafilas" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Generar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="generaTabla" style="display: none">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" id="tblTabla" style="color: #333333; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr style="color: White; background-color: #5D7B9D; font-weight: bold;">
              <th align="left">Nro
              </th>
              <th align="left">Cantidad
              </th>
              <th align="left" scope="col">Valor
              </th>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- FIN TAB2 -->

      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <!-- INICIA TAB3 -->
        3
      </div>
      <!-- FIN TAB3 -->
      <ul class="pager wizard">
        <li class="next"><a href="#">Siguiente</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: formulario]

[image: genera tabla]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

agregue var $ = jQuery; antes de la linea que me genera error

Fuente: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/typeerror-valid-is-not-a-function-not-working-after-upgrading-to-jquery-1-10-2

Comment: Por favor alguien que la agregue como respuesta por que yo ya no puedo hasta dentro de 2 días...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tiene incorrecto el `$('#fecharecepcion')` el input no tiene ese ID,  y sucede lo mismo con `$('#fechaenvio')`